# REST Service receive empty params

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, c#-4.0, rest

I'm trying to comunicate with my rest service but this one return always that my sended parameter is empty but in my client console he is filled.

Here is the Interface Class :

```
[ServiceContract]
    public interface IMyTest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(UriTemplate = "TestMe", RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped)]
        string TestMe(string parameter);        
    }
```

My svc method :

```
    public string TestMe(string parameter)
            {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(parameter)
                return "Empty";
            return "OK";
            }
```

My client :

```
string content = "{\"Param\" : \"TEST\"}";
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/MyTestURL/MyTest.svc/TestMe");
                request.Method = "POST";
                request.ContentType = "application/json";
                using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
                {
                    writer.Write(content);
                }

                var res = (WebResponse)request.GetResponse();

                StreamReader reader =
                  new StreamReader(res.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.UTF8);
                System.Console.WriteLine("Response");
                System.Console.WriteLine(reader.ReadToEnd().ToString());
```

Is my client code not ok ? My conifiguration not ok ? ...

Thanks.

Comment: Are you passing the content-length header as well?

Comment: i tested also to pass the content-lentgh but nothing change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i founded a good [tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/275279/Developing-WCF-Restful-Services-with-GET-and-POST)  that helped me to implement the method with the stream parameter. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get request as string, use Stream instead of String parameter

```
public void TestMe(Stream dataStream)
```

but if not, use serializable to Json objects as parameters.

Comment: i tested to change string into Stream but now i have the response 400 bad request.